# Multiple columns like Spreadsheet Tables using UICollectionView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Have to develop the UI with multiple Columns like Table in Excel sheets (Spreadsheets). Am trying to achieve using UICollectionView. Can anyone please guide me to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I've done something similar before. The easiest way to achieve it, in my experience, is to have a `UITableView` in which every cell has a `UICollectionView`. So in `tableView:dequeueReusableViewWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, you need to pass a weak reference to the data the cell has to show (and use that data as the dataSource for your `UICollectionView`).

Comment: Search for `swift spreadsheet` -- a number of examples out there for you to use as-is or to learn from to build your own.

Comment: Hi, check this may be it will be helpfull for you. https://github.com/badalpub1991/BASReport

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a 3rd party library out there, this one is pretty darn good.

https://github.com/glyuck/GlyuckDataGrid

[image]

It's not currently fully supporting Swift 4 out of the box and is not being maintained, but the library is small, and with minimal tweaks to the current code, you shouldn't have any issue getting it ready for Swift 4.

You could also Fork the repo, make the updates, and submit a PR. I hope it helps!